# Hidden Field Change on Select From Database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Having an issue with this problem and can't seem to find a current answer that fits.

I have a dynamic dropdown which is populated from a database table that I need to have a change event which inputs a different value from the same table into a hidden field.

```
<?php
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM dbProduct";
$data1 = mysql_query($query1);
?>

<select class="form-control" name="ProductName" id="ProductName">

<?php
    while($fetch_options = mysql_fetch_array($data1)){
?>

    <option id="<?php echo $fetch_options['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $fetch_options['ProductName']; ?>">

    <?php echo $fetch_options['ProductName']; ?></option>

    <?php
        }
    ?>

</select>

<input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="ProductType" id="ProductType" value="">
```

So when the ProductName select control is inputted by the user, the hidden ProductType field will be populated with dbProduct>ProductType associated with the product selected.

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937302/get-hidden-input-value-from-database-after-select-form) similar answer, only the select options aren't populated dynamically from the database.

Comment: You should look into mysqli or PDO as mysql is deprecated.

Comment: Changed it to include the close after query. Thanks

Comment: You could look into PHP and AJAX

Answer (score 0):

As i understand, you want to fetch product type with selected product
you can use jquery ajax that just return a product type like below.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       jQuery(function($){
            $('#ProductName').change(function(){
                var value = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                       type : 'GET', //or post what you want
                       url: 'any url of your websites that simply return text',
                       contentType : 'application/json', //or text/html
                       dataType: 'json',
                       data : JSON.stringify({ 'productName' : value })
                       success: function(data) {
                           $('#ProductType').val(data);
                       }
                  });
            });
       });
    </script>
```

Comment: @smilango I'm not sure if your problem is with the Ajax or the JQuery so here is a JQuery example to add the values once you get them. http://jsbin.com/gadofifeqe/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @Ankit I've create a page which outputs a table list of Products in the database, but I'm getting a syntax error with your code on **success: function(data)** any idea why?

Comment: just add comma ',' at the last of data  : JSON.stringify({ 'productName' : value })

Comment: @Ankit I've corrected the syntax error and the page runs but the hidden field doesn't update with any value. Am I missing something? Sorry still learning

Comment: @smilango : sorry, but i have to check everything to fix your error like ajax url and what that page is returning, i can't tell you exact without seeing anything.